# Why is there a difference when I use parenthesis in FILTER() vs when I dont? Is there a difference in logical evaluation?

Tags: function, filter, powerbi, dax

This is a code that I am writing with the purpose of calculating the latest date of my company's spare parts used, however, I would like to check certain conditions,

SP_USED[Product Number] = "92360122" OR SP_USED[Product Number] = "92360136" with their model numbers being either :

```
        SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-10" ||
        SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-20" ||
        SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-31" ||
        SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XR-10" ||
        SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XR-10"
```

I wrote a code which produces the wrong output (does not take into consideration the filtered table base on conditions and returning the max, instead it returns a max over all of the rows without filtering)

Code 1:

```
LUsedDateCombined = 
VAR currIB = SP_USED[Install Base]
VAR maxDateLastUsed = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(SP_USED[BRB Start Date]),
    FILTER(
        SP_USED,
        SP_USED[Product Number] = "92360122" || SP_USED[Product Number] = "92360136" &&
        
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-10" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-20" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-31" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XR-10" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XR-10"
        
    ),
    SP_USED[Install Base] = currIB 
)
RETURN
FORMAT(maxDateLastUsed, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

But once I add the parenthesis, it returns the corr output, giving me the max date based on my filtered conditions

Code 2:

```
LUsedDateCombined (Joanne) = 
VAR currIB = SP_USED[Install Base]
VAR maxDateLastUsed = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(SP_USED[BRB Start Date]),
    FILTER(
        SP_USED,
        SP_USED[Product Number] = "92360122" || SP_USED[Product Number] = "92360136" &&
        
            (SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-10" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-20" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XN-31" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XR-10" ||
            SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] = "XR-10")
        
    ),
    SP_USED[Install Base] = currIB 
)
RETURN
FORMAT(maxDateLastUsed, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

What could possibly be the cause?

After I realized this, I tried to put parenthesis in the first condition and remove parenthesis in the second, but it gives me the wrong output, I dont understand why the parenthesis and its position changes things.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Order of Operations - PEMDAS](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html). What's the difference between `true && false || true` and `true && (false || true)`?

Comment: Also consider simplifying your condition with `SP_USED[Product Number] IN {"92360122", "92360136"} && SP_USED[Model Number (Adjusted)] IN {"XN-10", "XN-20", "XN-31", "XR-10"}`